# How to find out raw weight values being used in Logistic Regression when using class_wight='balanced'?

Tags: python, logistic-regression

Using `class_weight='balanced'` in my logistics regression python script but i want to actually know the raw values/weights being utilized that the class weight balanced is picking.

I am using the sklearn package in python.

What I expect to see is something similar to `class_weight = {0: 0.28684210526315784, 1: 0.7131578947368422}` or some kind of value. However, this is masked when I use `class_weight = 'balanced'`. I want to know by using `'balanced'` what values is this ultimately using for my `1` and `0`.

Comment: we can't help you very much if you don't post a piece of your code, or at least mention if you're using sklearn or some other library, etc.

Comment: You are evidently asking a question about some specific framework. You need to be more specific. Also your question is very vague and you offer none of your current code. I'm afraid no one will be able to answer this question as you've written it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html

Exemplifying for binary classification (`targets = [0,1]`):

```
class_weights = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight( 'balanced', [0,1], y_train)
```